# What is proper way to WRITE "knock-knock"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, writing

What is a proper way to write knock-knock (the sound of knocking in the door) in Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here're some of them, listed from light sound to heavy:

```
笃笃
咚咚
嘭嘭/砰砰
咣咣 (usually used with 砸门)
```

Comment: A knock from police inspection : `查水表`

Comment: @mootmoot Why police check it? Not a staff of water supply company?

Comment: It is an Internet pun, where in China, authority try to gain access to private property without force entry.

Comment: @mootmoot not exactly. when you say something or do something to criticize the government or reveal a truth that the government doesn't want the public to know, the "big brother" will be annoyed and the police will come arrest you. " Checking the water meter " would be an excuse of the police when they ask you to open the door. Of course, it's just an internet slang used in an ironic/ funny way. In real life in China, a non-public critique won't lead to a concern of the government.